# Accessing an entry of Mat object in Opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm writing a program in c++ using opencv and I am having a bit of hard time with errors when trying to access and manipulate entries of a matrix.
Here's the code:

```
int l = (int)Lines.size();
    Mat sep_seam_map = Mat(n,l - 1, CV_64F, cvScalar(0.));// initialize the seperating seam map of coordinates.

    for (int k = 1; k < l - 1; k++){
        //apply constrained seam carving for each pair of text lines:

        int L_a = Lines[k].first.x;
        int L_b = Lines[k + 1].first.x;

        for (int row = 2; row < n; row++) {
            for (int col = L_a; col < L_b; col++) {
                //Defining the bounderies upon which to find the minimum value seams.
                int left = std::max(col - 1, L_a);
                int right = std::min(col + 1, L_b);
                double minpath,max;
                Mat last_row = energy_map.operator()(Range(row - 1, row), Range(left, right));
                minMaxLoc(last_row, &minpath, &max);

                //End Cases - 
                if (minpath == 0) { 
                    if (col > left)
                        energy_map.at<float>(row, col) = energy_map.at<float>(row - 1, right);
                    if (col < right)
                        energy_map.at<float>(row, col) = energy_map.at<float>(row - 1, left);
                    else
                        energy_map.at<float>(row, col) = energy_map.at<float>(row, col) (float)minpath;

                }


            }
```

The problems arrive when i try accessing the matrix - in the "End Cases", I'm getting this error: cv::Exception at memory location 0x00000000001AF050. Any clues anyone? this error happens again later in the code when i try to access the matrix again. I've tried declaring the 'sep_seam_map' using the 'zeroes' command but with no help.
Thanks A lot everyone.

**update:** the program write in the console window the following error:

```
Assertion faild: dims <= 2 && data && (unsigned)i0 < (unsigned)size.p[0] &&
(unsigned)(i1*DataType<_Tp>::channels) < (unsigned)(size.p[1]*channels()) &&
CV_ELEM_SIZE1(DataType<_Tp>::depth) == elemSize1()).
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `energy_map.at<float>()` is only valid if the type is CV_32F. for CV_64F use `energy_map.at<double>()`. also, running a *DEBUG* build should have thrown a proper exception.

Comment: Still getting the that error even though i've changed the type to CV_32F. also, I am running a debug build.

Comment: Can you add std::cout << "A/B/C etc" << std::endl; before each line of code to find the line that crashes?